# What is the most practical Solution to Data Management using SQLite on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, database-design, sqlite, memory-management

I'm developing an iPhone application and am new to Objective-C as well as SQLite. That being said, I have been struggling w/ designing a practical data management solution that is worthy of existing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the deal:

The majority of the data my application interacts with is stored in five tables in the local SQLite database. Each table has a corresponding Class which handles initialization, hydration, dehydration, deletion, etc. for each object/row in the corresponding table. Whenever the application loads, it populates five NSMutableArrays (one for each type of object). In addition to a Primary Key, each object instance always has an ID attribute available, regardless of hydration state. In most cases it is a UUID  which I can then easily reference.

Before a few days ago, I would simply access the objects via these arrays by tracking down their UUID. I would then proceed to hydrate/dehydrate them as I needed. However, some of the objects I have also maintain their own arrays which reference other object's UUIDs. In the event that I must track down one of these "child" objects via it's UUID, it becomes a bit more difficult.

In order to avoid having to enumerate through one of the previously mentioned arrays to find a "parent" object's UUID, and then proceed to find the "child's" UUID, I added a DataController w/ a singleton instance to simplify the process.

I had hoped that the DataController could provide a single access point to the local database and make things easier, but I'm not so certain that is the case. Basically, what I did is create multiple NSMutableDicationaries. Whenever the DataController is initialized, it enumerates through each of the previously mentioned NSMutableArrays maintained in the Application Delegate and creates a key/value pair in the corresponding dictionary, using the given object as the value and it's UUID as the key.

The DataController then exposes procedures that allow a client to call in w/ a desired object's UUID to retrieve a reference to the actual object. Whenever their is a request for an object, the DataController automatically hydrates the object in question and then returns it. I did this because I wanted to take control of hydration out of the client's hands to prevent dehydrating an object being referenced multiple times.

I realize that in most cases I could just make a mutable copy of the object and then if necessary replace the original object down the road, but I wanted to avoid that scenario if at all possible. I therefore added an additional dictionary to monitor what objects are hydrated at any given time using the object's UUID as the key and a fluctuating count representing the number of hydrations w/out an offset dehydration. My goal w/ this approach was to have the DataController automatically dehydrate any object once it's "hydration retainment count" hit zero, but this could easily lead to significant memory leaks as it currently relies on the caller to later call a procedure that decreases the hydration retainment count of the object. There are obviously many cases when this is just not obvious or maybe not even easily accomplished, and if only one calling object fails to do so properly I encounter the exact opposite scenario I was trying to prevent in the first place. Ironic, huh?

Anyway, I'm thinking that if I proceed w/ this approach that it will just end badly. I'm tempted to go back to the original plan but doing so makes me want to cringe and I'm sure there is a more elegant solution floating around out there. As I said before, any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd also be aware (as I'm sure you are) that CoreData is just around the corner, and make sure you make the right choice for the future.

Comment: I've considered holding out for CoreData, but it would be nice to have something on the App Store before that time comes. I also would eventually like to port my application to other platforms which obviously won't be supporting CoreData.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered implementing this via the NSCoder interface? Not sure that it wouldn't be more trouble than it's worth, but if what you want is to extract all the data out into an in-memory object graph, and save it back later, that might be appropriate. If you're actually using SQL queries to limit the amount of in-memory data, then obviously, this wouldn't be the way to do it.

Comment: I haven't considered that at this point. However, I forgot to mention that I also have tables designed w/ the sole purpose of relating two objects using their UUIDs. For example, playersForGame is a two column table that links each player to the games they participated in, and these tables I do use SQL queries on. I had a terrible professor for my Database class in college(who got fired the semester after I took it), so I'm sure there is a better way of doing this... I just don't know it yet :)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go w/ Core Data after all.